# How Disable Windows Scroll in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I wrote some code and I want to capture the scroll event in my code, so when the user scrolls my div the scroll should only work in my div and the page scroll event should not be called ( fired )

How I can do this?

Edit: I find the answer: I'm now using `preventDefault()` and it's now working

Answer (score 0):

The CSS for this is:

```
body.noscroll { overflow:hidden; }
body.doscroll { overflow:auto; }
```

Just make it default and tell your javascript to handle the scrolling instead, it should work fine.

Comment: no i dont want to change any thing in page it's a plugin and may use in any page - i just want when mouse is over this div the scroll event dosent work in page

Comment: Can't you onmouseover disable scroll, onmouseout enable scroll?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jQuery like this:

```
$('body').css({'overflow': 'hidden'});
```

Like this you can disable the scroll as an event-handler after listen an event.
In a function like this:

```
$('element').on('event', function(){
   $('body').css({'overflow': 'hidden'});   
});
```

For activate the scroll again in case you need it after.
It's like this:

```
$('body').css({'overflow': 'auto'});
```

In the same way you will be able to handle an event with that function to bring back the scroll.

Hope this Help.